# Error: No Such Package when bundling Meteor.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, meteorite

When my Meteor app is being bundled (using Meteor UP `mup deploy`), it gives a set of errors below. Do I have to manually install (globally?) these packages using Meteorite before bundling?

```
$ mup deploy

Meteor-UP : Production Quality Meteor Deployments
--------------------------------------------------

Bundling Started: /var/www/test-app
Bundling Error:  Command failed:
-------------------STDOUT-------------------
rss: updating npm dependencies -- rss...
mailchimp: updating npm dependencies -- mailchimp...
Errors prevented bundling:
While building the application:
error: no such package: 'database-forms'
error: no such package: 'crypto-md5'
error: no such package: 'momentjs'
error: no such package: 'iron-router'
error: no such package: 'nprogress'

-------------------STDERR-------------------
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run `mrt update` first

Once everything has updated and the packages have downloaded then you can run `mup`

Comment: Thanks. So the sequence is `mup setup`, `mrt update`, `mup deploy`.

Comment: yes. exactly. mup expects, meteor app is working properly on the local machine.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error, and mrt update won't work. :( I've filed an issue here: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/17

Comment: Oh, what I had to do was update meteorite. `npm update -g meteorite`

Comment: This updates the packages in your app to the latest versions or if they don't exist installs them. `npm update -g meteorite` updates the version of meteorite, which runs `mrt` for these commands. You might have had an older version

Comment: Saved my day! Apparently you have to update to see the package (or at least make the meteor sees the package)